# Equation with note and tag

Tags: equations

Given the following set of equations as an example:

```
`...
\begin{align}
    x &= y^2 + 3 \\
    y + 3 &= 11
\end{align}`
```

The equations will be center aligned with respect to the "=" sign and tagged on the left with equation numbers.  Is there a way I can add a note to the side of one of the equations without affecting the positioning of the equations (i.e. not shifting the group of equations upon insertion of the note)?

I've tried '{flalign}', but the group of equations shifts upon addition of the note.  I've tried to find a way to add an additional tag on the right, but have come up empty.  I've used '\qquad', but that, too, shifts the group of equations.

Here is the reason: aesthetics.  If I have two groups of equations that are centered (using gather or similar), the group of equations that includes the note will be shifted from the other groups of equations.  I just think this looks sloppy... call me picky.

Example output:

```
(left)         (center)           (right)
(1)            xyz = abc
(2)            abc = xyz
{next math group}
(3)            cba = abc
(4)            yzx = cba        some text
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114273/21344) might help. You could remove the `$`s from the definition of `\Domain` if you don't always need math mode, and rename the command to suit your semantic usage. I remember seeing other related questions too; I'll keep looking a bit.

Comment: for a line of text *between* two aligned equations, use `\intertext`.  (requires `amsmath`, and i'm sure this has been asked/answered before.)

Comment: I realize that I can insert text _between_ equations using '\intertext', but I would like the note to be _beside_ the equation.  If there were a way to add an additional tag to the right a given equation, that would also solve my problem.

Comment: Does this answer help?  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159800/how-to-put-a-text-label-before-an-equation/159803#159803.  The first solution uses `falign` but puts a phantom of the note on the opposite side, thus preserving the centering.

Comment: @Steven : I think it just might work, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `flalign`and `\llap`, so no `\phantom` is used. Two cases may happen : either the note is short enough to not overlap the equation, or it is too long. For the first case, I define a `shorteqnote` command; in the second case, the note has to be written on the next line; a `\longeqnote` command is defined. A note is supposed to be at most one line long (anyway, would that be sensible?).

```
        \documentclass[ a4paper, leqno]{article}

        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        \usepackage[showframe, textwidth = 15cm, nomarginpar, noheadfoot]{geometry}

        \usepackage{mathtools}

        \newcommand{\shorteqnote}[1]{ &  & \text{\small\llap{#1}}}
        \newcommand{\longeqnote}[1]{& & \\ \notag  &  &  &  &  & \text{\small\llap{#1}}}

        \begin{document}

        This results in this :
        \begin{flalign}
         &  & xyz  & = abc \\
          &  &           abc  & = xyz  &  & \\
        \shortintertext{next math group: }
            &  &           cba &= abc \shorteqnote{(A short note)} \\
            &  &        x^2 + y^2  + z^2& = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \longeqnote{(A longer note:  True only in characteristic 2)}
        \end{flalign}

        \end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: What package has \shortnote in it?

Comment: 'Twas a typo for `\shorteqnote`. Thanks for pointing it. I've made the correction.

Comment: Thanks. I am not a very good latex person and don't know what's out there. Have to look a lot of things up.

Comment: Oh, it's very simple: `\llap` is a plain TeX command  which inserts a box at the left of the cursor (from right to left, so to say), then sets the cursor at the position it had before  insertion. Thus the width of the inserted box is not taken into account. This way you might, for instance, write in the left margin. Similarly there  is a `\rlap` command.

Comment: Thanks! That explanation of \llap is very helpful. I have everything working, except that the equation numbers are still coming out on the right hand side.

Comment: Even with the `leqno` option of the document class?

Comment: I think the problem is something to do with using subfiles. The leqno option may not be carrying through to the subfile somehow. If I take the subfile on its own yes it works fine. Thanks v. much. I will try to chase up what is going wrong with the subfiles.

Comment: Maybe a package that inhibits the option?

Comment: The subfiles package claims not to do very much, but it may be preventing the leqno option being passed via documentclass. Is there another way of setting left equation numbers not via documentclass?

Comment: Strange… I've just looked at the doc of subfiles, and it doesn't sem to interfere. Just in case: try loading  `mathtools` with option `leqno`.