# Equation with tags on both sides

Tags: equations, alignment, tag

The exact demand is that I want to put the citation on the left and the usual arabic label on the right.

I've found 3 solutions so far:

1. Use environment `flalign`. Source: [How to number math equations from both sides?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334081/how-to-number-math-equations-from-both-sides)
2. Use `\makebox` to create an environment from scratch, with the help of `\hfill`. Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574793/199226
3. Use package `zref` or `tikz` to fetch the exact coordinates and place the text there with other packages, i.e. `tikz`, `textpos` or `eso-pic`.

The following MWE contains the default `equation` for alignment reference, solution 1, solution 2 and an instance of solution 3.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}

% source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/574795/199226
\newcommand{\ltag}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(tmp.base),remember picture]
        \node[inner sep=0pt](tmp){\vphantom{1}};
        \begin{scope}[overlay]
            \path (current page text area.west|-tmp.base)
                node[anchor=base west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]{#1};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{Example}{Equation}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \frac{Example}{Equation}\ltag{tikz}
\end{equation}
\begin{flalign}
    \rlap{\text{flalign with balancing}}%
    \phantom{(\theequation)}%
    &&\frac{Example}{Equation}&&
\end{flalign}
\begin{flalign}
    \rlap{\text{flalign}}%
    &&\frac{Example}{Equation}&&
\end{flalign}
\makebox[\linewidth]{
    \refstepcounter{equation}
    \rlap{makebox}\hfill
    $\displaystyle \frac{Example}{Equation}$
    \hfill\llap{(\theequation)}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem of solution 1 is that the equation is not exactly centered. I've tried adding `\phantom{(\theequation)}` on the left for balancing, but there is still a small offset compared to the usual `equation` environment. See also: https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=31268
Also notice that `flalign` has different line spacing.

Solution 2 also has alignment issues. See MWE.

Solution 3 can give the desired result, but I suppose there should be a cleaner way that operates locally, instead of saving some data globally.

PS: I also want `\eqref` and `\autoref` to work properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the text to the right aligned label, but shifted to the left.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\ltag#1{%
\stepcounter{equation}%
\tag*{}%
\def\df@tag{(\theequation)\llap{\rlap{#1}\hspace{\columnwidth}}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{equation}\label{aa}
    \frac{Example}{Equation}
\end{equation}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{equation}
\ltag{left text}\label{bb}
    \frac{Example}{Equation}
\end{equation}


\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{equation}
    \frac{Example}{Equation}
\end{equation}


aa\eqref{aa} aa\eqref{bb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost perfect. One thing is that `eqref` has two pairs of parenthesis for your solution. `\tag{\theequation\llap{\rlap{\phantom{(}aaa}\hspace{\textwidth}}}` seems to work.

Comment: Out of curiousity, does `\tag` stop the automatic counter?

Comment: @putianyi888 No it is worse than that the left side text appears in eqref off the left margin try `\hspace*{\textwidth}aa\eqref{bb}`  I will fix...

Comment: @putianyi888  updated answer

Comment: Can you make it work for other environments like `align`, `multline` and possibly in `subequations` and `multicols`? Shall I make another question for this?

Comment: multicols is easy just replace `\textwidth` by `\columnwidth`  the same mechanism will work for ams alignments but the exact place to hook in may be different, I'll try to look later @putianyi888

Comment: replacing works. It works for `equation` in `subequations` and `multicols` at present.

Comment: May I open a new question for `\align` and `\alignat`?

Comment: @putianyi888 you can ask as many questions as you like:-)