# Align and alignat environments with tags on both sides

Tags: align, alignment, tag

This is a follow-up question of [Equation with tags on both sides](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664315/equation-with-tags-on-both-sides/) which tackles the `equation` environment. How do I make it work for `align` and `alignat`?

For reference, the solution for `equation` is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/664316/199226

which is pasted below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\ltag#1{%
\stepcounter{equation}%
\tag*{}%
\def\df@tag{(\theequation)\llap{\rlap{#1}\hspace{\columnwidth}}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{equation}\label{aa}
    \frac{Example}{Equation}
\end{equation}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{equation}
\ltag{left text}\label{bb}
    \frac{Example}{Equation}
\end{equation}


\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{equation}
    \frac{Example}{Equation}
\end{equation}


aa\eqref{aa} aa\eqref{bb}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please put a minimal working example. It is very easy that somebody give you an answer.

Comment: @Sebastian the MWE is in the linked answer. Is it recommended to paste it here anyway?

Comment: Yes it is better.