# Adding number equation and note in an equation

Tags: numbering

So, i want to add number equation in left and note in right, i follow step here [Equation with note and tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164983/equation-with-note-and-tag) , it did work, but there is problem which is the note itself is not edge right and oftenly very close to the equation, also sometime it mixed the equation. How to fix it?

Comment: How should it be handled if the note runs over the equation?

Comment: im sorry, im new to tex, so I dont understand what you mean?

Comment: I guess he meant: What happens if the equation is long and the note long as well. Both will take up the same space.

Comment: no no, the equation is only abc = xyz and the note is only (from assumptions we have) that equation and note is only for trying the code.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full, yet minimal, example code, demonstrating the problem?